# Get ID from an input defined in the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

Not sure how clear the title is.
I have file uploading script. An input field is created dynamically with javascript with the name of testdata. One input field is created for every file that the user decides to upload. My model so far just gets the value of the field.

```
 public string testdata { get; set; }
```

Later in my controller I'm getting the value and writing it to a file.
Problem is when uploading multiple files, the controller collects the values from all inputs and write them all together on every line. What I want is to have a seperate line with the value from each input (each upload). The controller does simply what I asked it to do. I don't know how to access the id of the input field. I know I need to change my model but not sure how. Any help would be apreciated. Thanks!

The controller, in case it wasn't very clear:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UploadsModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        string uploadDir = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads");
        foreach (string fileKey in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileKey];
            StreamWriter tw = System.IO.File.AppendText(Path.Combine(uploadDir, "post_data.txt"));
            tw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now + " " + file.FileName + " " + model.testdata);
            tw.Close();
            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadDir, file.FileName));
        }

        //could go somewhere else...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

EDIT:
Found a workaround. Will create dynamically a hidden field for each regular field. Will pass the value of the first one to it, will create new property in my model and when uploading and saving, I will compare the file name and the hidden field value.

Comment: Theoretically your IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files should be in your UploadsModel object. Can you show the View?

Comment: The View is irrelevent in this case, the form itself is created on the clientside.

Comment: Not irrelevant whatsoever as the View creates the IDs that the Controller picks up. If these are not correct then the Controller cannot serialize the data passed to it.

Comment: I want to access the ID, not create it. It is already created by the javascript. <input type="text" name="testdata" id="id-' + file.uid + '" class="' + alt + '"  />

Comment: This is where your ID needs to match up to your ViewModel, you need, say a FileInput property as a String in your UploadsModel, then do @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileInput) and then this will be automatically sent as a value in your UploadsModel.

Comment: I think my question is not very clear. I do catch the value. I want to catch the id, so I cant control which value goes where. My View is just an empty div in which the javascript inserts the controls.